# add url to html extension Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am starting to write a extension for chrome. For this extension I like to add automatically the url on the bar to an text field of my extension. When I click on my extension u popup shows a form with a   field. The value must be set to the URL of the page i Visit.

I work normally with Jquery, and maybe the answer can fit in the jquery.

I hope I enplane everything well and thank you for any answer

Update:

This must be the answer

```
     populateForm();
function populateForm() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    console.debug(tab);
    naam.value = tab.title;
    url.value = tab.url;
    }
    )};
```

Comment: Well if naam and url are DOMElements then I don't see why that wont work. What error do you see when you inspect your popup? (right click on your popup, and choose Inspect, then look at the console window).

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets and parentheses are misplaced. Try using this:

```
function populateForm() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        console.debug(tab);
        naam.value = tab.title;
        url.value = tab.url;
    });
}
populateForm();
```